# Can PowerShell tab completion work like VS 2010 Pascal Case Intellisense?

Tags: powershell, tab-completion

In Visual Studio 2010, if there is a method like `AlphaBetaGamma()`, you can reach it by typing `someObject.ABG[tab]` (see for instance [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/02/09/using-the-new-intellisense-pascal-case-vstipedit0017.aspx)).

In PowerShell, when I have a cmdlet like `Update-Package` can I reach it by typing something like `UP[tab]` or `U-P[tab]`? (I know these two things don't work, just trying to show what I'm looking for.)

If there is no such tab completion feature, what is the least amount of key strokes to execute `Update-Package`? I currently do it by typing `update-p[tab]`, which is 9 key strokes. I can also do `up[tab][down][down][down][down][Enter]` but that is too context-dependent (there might be too many matches for my two-letter prefix).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the PowerTab module - http://powertab.codeplex.com/

You can do the camel case completion for methods and properties, but for cmdlets you can extend it pretty easily I believe.

You can also do something like `up%[tab]` to get the list etc.

Update:

Don't have time to do a tabexpansion implementation / extending PowerTab, but something like below should easily give the cmdlets available when you do tab with the first letters:

```
get-command U*-P* | ?{$_.commandtype -eq "Cmdlet"} | select -expand name
```

Comment: I've seen PowerTab before, though I'm not sure if it supports Pascal case completion. Does it?

Comment: @Borek - It does for properties and methods, but not for cmdlets.